# Select student data from a table and include parent email address from another table

Tags: sql-server

I am pretty new to SQL and I'm having trouble creating a Select statement that works for the above task.  I need a Select statement that gets me something like this:

'''Select
Students.ID
Students.Last_name
Students.First_name
Emailaddress.emailaddress AS Parent_email'''

Below are the tables I'm working with at the moment.  Any help would be amazing.

[image: Table Connections]

Comment: Welcome to dba.se!  Please read this to improve your question and increase the likelihood of getting an answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Generally questions like this would require some sample data so that a properly functional query could be validated. However, we can use this as an opportunity to look at how the query might get started.

**Assumptions:**

1. a student may have multiple parents (or guardians) or none at all
2. a parent may have multiple email addresses or none at all
3. data in the database may be incomplete

**The `SELECT` Statement:**

You have the basics in place, but remember the commas. These are important:

```
SELECT Students.ID, Students.Last_Name, Students.First_Name, Emailaddress.EmailAddress AS Parent_Email
```

**Linking the Sources:**

The student is the primary record, so we know we will need this:

```
   FROM Students
```

A student may or may not have parents and/or guardians, so it may be worthwhile to use an `OUTER JOIN` to link the next tables. We know the `StudentContactAssoc` table has contact associations, and that table will reference `Person` to get the name of the person to contact, so let's do this:

```
   FROM Students stu LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentContactAssoc sca ON stu.DCID = sca.StudentDCID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN Person p ON sca.PersonID = p.ID
```

Note that the table names have been given aliases such as `stu` and `sca`. This is to save a whole lot of typing and to make things a bit easier to read.

Now that we have the person, let's look at the remaining tables:

```
   FROM Students stu LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentContactAssoc sca ON stu.DCID = sca.StudentDCID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN Person p ON sca.PersonID = p.ID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonEmailAddressAssoc pea ON p.ID = pea.PersonID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN EmailAddress ea ON pea.EmailAddressID = ea.EmailAddressID
```

If we do not need the name of the parent or guardian, we can eliminate the `Person` reference altogether, as it's an unnecessary `JOIN` when `StudentContactAssoc` and `PersonEmailAddressAssoc` both have the required `PersonID` reference:

```
   FROM Students stu LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentContactAssoc sca ON stu.DCID = sca.StudentDCID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN Person p ON sca.PersonID = p.ID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonEmailAddressAssoc pea ON p.ID = pea.PersonID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN EmailAddress ea ON pea.EmailAddressID = ea.EmailAddressID
```

**Filtering:**

Now we need to identify if there is anything that should go into a `WHERE` clause. Because we are using `OUTER JOIN` to link data, we cannot have any filters for the outer-joined tables in the `WHERE`. We can, however, filter on a student record. For example:

```
 WHERE Last_Name = 'Smith' and First_Name = 'Morty'
```

We will want to ensure the email address in `EmailAddress` is partially believable, so we'll likely want to add a filter there as well. For example:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN EmailAddress ea ON pea.EmailAddressID = ea.EmailAddressID
                               AND ea.EmailAddress LIKE '%@%'
```

<sub>**Note:** This is probably unnecessary for the sake of your needs, but you'd be surprised at how often email address fields in corporate CMSes have values that are most certainly *not* email addresses.</sub>

**Ordering:**

Finally, we get to associate the order of importance. Ideally we would expect at least one `IsPrimaryEmailAddress` to exist for each `Person`, but do not count on this. There may also be situations where `IsPrimaryEmailAddress` points to a non-existent `EmailAddress` record. So, to take some of this into consideration, we can do something like this:

```
 ORDER BY IsPrimaryEmailAddress DESC, EmailAddressPriorityOrder
```

The above assumes that `IsPrimaryEmailAddress` is a `bit` or an enumerated `Y`/`N` column, and that `EmailAddressPriorityOrder` treats lower numbers as higher priorities (Priority 1 is higher than Priority 5, for example).

**Putting It Together:**

Now that all of this has been laid out, let's put it together:

```
SELECT stu.ID, stu.Last_Name, stu.First_Name, ea.EmailAddress AS Parent_Email
   FROM Students stu LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentContactAssoc sca ON stu.DCID = sca.StudentDCID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonEmailAddressAssoc pea ON sca.PersonID = pea.PersonID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN EmailAddress ea ON pea.EmailAddressID = ea.EmailAddressID
                                                    AND ea.EmailAddress LIKE '%@%'
 WHERE stu.Last_Name = 'Smith' and stu.First_Name = 'Morty'
 ORDER BY stu.Last_Name, stu.First_Name, stu.ID, pea.IsPrimaryEmailAddress DESC, pea.EmailAddressPriorityOrder
```

This query will return all parent/guardian email addresses for students named Morty Smith, sorted by student name, student ID, then email priority.

**Things You May Need to Do Later:**

- return a list of all students with just a single contact email address
- return a list of all students without a parent/guardian email address
- return a list of all students with invalid parent/guardian email addresses
- add columns to the return list to show which addresses are primary and/or their priority number

Welcome to the fun world of SQL